# Bugs in compiling QEMU

Tags: software-installation

I want to install qemu1.0.1 on Linux octeon 2.6.32.13.
For some reason I cannot use latest version of qemu.
It configure successfully for mips64.
But in compilation it gives following error

```
qemu-ga.o: In function `asprintf':
/usr/include/bits/stdio2.h:158: undefined reference to `__asprintf_chk'
qemu-ga.o: In function `conn_channel_send_buf':
/home/hafiz.shafiq/work_qemu/qemu-1.0.1/qemu-ga.c:220: undefined reference to `g_debug'
qemu-ga.o: In function `process_event':
/home/hafiz.shafiq/work_qemu/qemu-1.0.1/qemu-ga.c:303: undefined reference to `g_debug'
qemu-ga.o: In function `process_command':
/home/kics/hafiz.shafiq/work_qemu/qemu-1.0.1/qemu-ga.c:279: undefined reference to `g_debug'
qemu-timer-common.o: In function `init_get_clock':
/home/hafiz.shafiq/work_qemu/qemu-1.0.1/qemu-timer-common.c:57: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
qga/guest-agent-commands.o: In function `qmp_guest_file_write':
/home/hafiz.shafiq/work_qemu/qemu-1.0.1/qga/guest-agent-commands.c:249: undefined reference to `g_base64_decode'
qga/guest-agent-commands.o: In function `qmp_guest_file_read':
/home/hafiz.shafiq/work_qemu/qemu-1.0.1/qga/guest-agent-commands.c:224: undefined reference to `g_base64_encode'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [qemu-ga] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compile a software project from scratch - I normally start with installing the build dependencies for the version there is included in Ubuntu by doing:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qemu
```

That ensures you have all libraries and the headers files your package is depended on. If your own fresh downloaded source don't use any new libraries you should have the needed libraries to build it.

From your errors, it look like you at least need libglib2.0-dev